# Logic question: Is ~(P&Q) equivalent to (~P&~Q)?

Tags: logic

Where '~' is the sign for naught, and stands for "it is not the case that".

My question is, is "it is not the case that (P&Q)" equivalent to "it is not the case that P & it is not the case that Q"?

Comment: How many examples have you thought through?

Answer (score 5):

**No**

If anyone has questions like this, the *first* thing to do should always be to build a test matrix to see if your theory is sound or not.

```
P    Q    ~(P&Q)  (~P&~Q)
        +--------+-------+
T    T  |   F    |   F   |  same
T    F  |   T    |   F   |  not same
F    T  |   T    |   F   |  not same
F    F  |   T    |   T   |  same
        +--------+-------+
```

In four lines of work, we immediately get our result.   ~(P&Q) is not the same as (~P&~Q).  You can do this for any logic, and it saves a lot of time waiting for answers from StackExchange!

*What you are actually looking for is DeMorgan's law: ~(P&Q) -> (~P | ~Q).  Note that the operation changes from AND to OR.*

Answer (score -3):

the equivalence you are looking for is this:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws

Have a nice day!

Comment: This is not De Morgan's law, because of parenthesis and the difference between v and &...

Comment: Yes it is. The law only states that the negation of a logical product is the same of the negation of the sum of its components. Its not about "and" or "or", but both.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @iphigenie My friend, if you are so unsatisfied with my answer, be the better man and provide the questioner with one. It's easy to criticize while you do nothing isn't it? All your argumentation is based on the assumption that I have the obligation to open the questioner's brain and put the information there for him; I shall not, and if he wants to learn he must read from the proper sources, and I'm not one. I would have putted De Morgan's original proof's link, but I couldn't find it.